# vb.net Log into website

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to log into `Rueters.com` through my VB.net program. So far my code works until I click the "Sign In" button. No errors occur, but it doesn't log in either.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://commerce.us.reuters.com/login/pages/login/login.do?backUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reuters.com%2F&backParameterEncoded=false&source=portfolio&flow=PORTFOLIO&entry_source=registration")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginName").SetAttribute("value", "username")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password")

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("class") = "button" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

**Sorry I forgot to include the HTML! Here it is:**

```
<div class="label">
    Email</div>
  <div class="textfield">
    <input type="text" size="40" maxlength="100" name="loginName" value="username" />
  </div>
  <div class="label">
    Password</div>
  <div class="textfield">
    <input type="password" value="" size="40" maxlength="20" name="password" />
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="flag" /> 
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="if(this.checked) this.form.flag.value='true'; else this.form.flag.value='false';" id="RememberCredentialsCBID" checked="checked" /> 
    <label class="label"  for="RememberCredentialsCBID">Remember me on this computer</label>
  </div>
  <div id="loginErr" class="label error">
  </div>  
  <div class="submit">
    <div class="button"><input type="image" src="/resources_v2/images/btn_sign_in.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="textfield">
       <a href="/login/restorePassword">Forgot your password?</a>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginName").SetAttribute("value", "username")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "password")

    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("type") = "image" Then
            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("src") = "https://commerce.us.reuters.com/resources_v2/images/btn_sign_in.gif" Then

                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

            End If
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: It says "UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled" "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Comment: As soon WebBrowser1 begins to load I get a security warning.  It says "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage."  If I click No then I get the UnauthorizedAccessException error shown above.  If I click Yes then I am able to login successfully.  How do I programatically click the yes button so that I don't have to do it manually everytime?

Comment: In the Webbrowser1 properties, change ScriptErrorsSuppressed to True